# My terminal (iTerm2) suddenly has a new prompt

Tags: shell, terminal, iterm2

I just opened a new tab in iTerm2, and the prompt is now 
`unknown48437c7db712:~alecwilson $`.
In the tab that was already open, I checked, and the prompt used to be `tests-MacBook-Air:~ $`. It's asking me to provide my RSA key for github but doesn't seem to be misbehaving otherwise. Any idea what is going on?

**UPDATE:** Weirdly enough, I did some work in my text editor waiting for an answer, then reopened iTerm2 (the 3rd time I've restarted it), and the prompt is back to one that makes sense, although for some reason, now it's `tests-Air:~ alecwilson`, rather than the original prompt. Still no idea what happened.

Comment: What is `PS1` set to in your shell (What does `declare -p PS1` output?)?

Comment: `declare -- PS1="\\h:\\W \\u\\\$ "`

Comment: Then the bit before the `:` there is your computer's hostname. So if it changes then your hostname is changing.

Comment: Thanks, useful info. Still completely lost as to why it happened, but nothing seems broken and it's been a day now, so guess I'll just chalk it up to something happening in the background I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unclear on how this happened, it's stopped occurring since I moved to zsh and cleaned up all my dotfiles, but for anyone who gets here in the future, changing the hostname of your computer then restarting the terminal app you are using does the trick.